# Object parented to a bone moves twice faster than the armature root bone

Tags: bones, constraints, parent

I'm rigging a wheel and When I move the root bone of the car armature, the wheel move twice faster than the armature, The rotation is ok, but I can't find the way to make the wheel move ok.

Video showing the issue:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Sdm_jfSCRGp0vMJKFW31vClcU1no6Sgy

Please help! Thamkyou!

Comment: Probably the root bone also has influence on the wheel, which is wrong. You should remove it.

Comment: It's not the root bone. I find The wheel it's being affected by the bone wich makes the rotation (and position) of the wheel (parented just to that bone of the armature), AND the mesh deform modifier that makes the squash and stretch of the wheel. But I cant find the way to make it work having control of the two parameters.

Comment: Actually if I sich off the armature modifier in the mesh deform box the wheel moves properly.